# Use case for "sets of tuple data" in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

When we specify the data for a set we have the ability to give it tuples of data. For example, we could write in our .dat file the following:

```py
 set A : 1  2  3  :=
     1   +  -  -  
     2   -  -  + 
     3   -  +  +
```

This would specify that we would have 4 tuples in our set: (1,1), (2,3), (3,2), (3,3)

But I guess that I am struggling to understand exactly why we would want to do this? Furthermore, suppose we instantiated a Set object in our code as:

```py
model.Aset = RangeSet(4, dimen=2)
```

Would this then specify that our tuples would have the indices 1, 2, 3, and 4?

I am thinking that specifying tuples in our set could potentially be useful when working with some data in which it's important to have a bit of a "spatial" understanding of the problem. But I would be curious to hear from the community what the potential applications of specifying set data this way might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common place this appears is when you're trying to model edges between nodes in a network. Networks aren't usually completely dense (have edges between every pair of nodes) so it's beneficial to represent just the edges that appear using a sparse set of tuples.

Comment: In theory, do you think it would be feasible to model a set of Tuple pairs to resemble a grid? For instance, a 2x2 grid made up of four tuples (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2) OR would it be better to model the grid indices separately as their own set?

Comment: My own modelling problem is quite similar to the spatial structure of a chessboard.

Comment: It depends on how you plan to iterate over them and if you need access to the individual indices. It's easy to create a 2 dimensional set as a product of two 1 dimensional sets (Set operations supported in Pyomo: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Sets.html#operations)